# Convert associative arrays to map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have two `String[]` with identical lengths. They are "associative arrays" in the sense that the string values of one are the **keys** and the string values in the other are the **values**:

```
String[] keys = { 'fizz', 'buzz', 'bupo' }
String[] values = { 'true', 'false', 'yes' }
```

I want to take these two associative arrays and convert them into a `Map<String,String>` with some Groovy magic. So far I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
Map<String,String> kvPairs = [keys, values]
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String[] keys = [ "fizz", "buzz", "bupo" ] 
String[] vals = [ "true", "false", "yes" ]
Map<String, String> kvPairs = [ keys, vals ].transpose()​.collectEntries()​
```

Result:

```
[fizz:true, buzz:false, bupo:yes]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said

> I have two String[] with identical lengths.

then you can take advantage of `eachWithIndex` feature of groovy

If you have

```
String[] keys = [ 'fizz', 'buzz', 'bupo' ]
String[] values = [ 'true', 'false', 'yes' ]
```

then you can simply do like

```
Map kvPairs = [:]

​keys.eachWithIndex{ element, index ->
    kvPairs << [(element) : values[index]]
}
println kvPairs
```

Output :

```
[fizz:true, buzz:false, bupo:yes]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly magical but it does the job. You can run this in the Groovy console.

```
String[] keys = ['fizz', 'buzz', 'bupo']
String[] values = ['true', 'false', 'yes']

Map<String, String> result = [:]

keys.eachWithIndex { key, index ->
  result[key] = values[index]
}

// show the result
println result
```

### Aside

The syntax you used to create an array is not valid in Groovy (or Java)

```
String[] keys = { 'fizz', 'buzz', 'bupo' }
```